# SQL Server use of FETCH OFFSET with complex statements

Tags: sql-server, performance

I use `OFFSET FETCH` syntax to get pagination done in SQL Server for my web application.

**NOTE**: the application has a user interface where a user can build his view, selecting the columns, those columns can be referenced values.

This works pretty fine with *simple* SQL statement but gets real slow if my SQL statements becomes too complex.

Example table with 10k rows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
         id, title
     FROM mytable) t
ORDER BY title 
      OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Assume, this query takes < 1s in SQL Server Management Studio.

Now I start implement referenced tables to my statement.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
         id, title,
         (SELECT value 
          FROM table_reference 
          WHERE id = ref_id) AS ref_value,
         (SELECT value 
          FROM table_reference2 
          WHERE id = ref_id2) AS ref_value2
     FROM 
         mytable) t
ORDER BY title 
      OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

This still performs well.

Now I do use the referenced values in my WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
         id, title,
         (SELECT value 
          FROM table_reference 
          WHERE id = ref_id) AS ref_value,
         (SELECT value 
          FROM table_reference2 
          WHERE id = ref_id2) AS ref_value2
     FROM 
         mytable) t
WHERE 
    ref_value LIKE '%something%'
ORDER BY title 
      OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Now my query is going from < 1s to 14seconds.

As my investigations from query analyzer and web I saw that `OFFSET` is the performance issue here due the way it works. Most web information praise `FETCH OFFSET` as easy to use and fast, but I could not find any detail info about bottlenecks and performance issues.

So as the UI also allow to define which columns are used for "full like searches" I seek for a solution to manage the way those values can be used and still no not crash my performance.

I thought about creating another column which holds the selected value, but if the reference changes this value is outdated. Also a trigger won't work on the referenced table to update as this is getting to complex and not maintainable.

I never took a look at it, but might computed columns be a option to check if this works? Or any other good advice for this specific problem?

Thanks, Yves

Comment: When you use a leading wildcard on a LIKE clause, SQL Server will perform a full-table scan, which will always be _very slow_ with a large table. You need to implement Full Text search and use `CONTAINS` instead

Comment: Use `CHARINDEX('smoething', ref_value) > 1` instead of `ref_value LIKE '%something%'`